# Prevent upscaling with scrset?

Tags: html, srcset

Is it possible to prevent upscaling when using `scrset`?

Here's a jsbin showing what I'm talking about:

https://jsbin.com/bukupuq

The browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari) are using the largest image to fill the container, even though its width (500px) is smaller. I would expect that it would intelligently use the best image given the viewport width, but *not* upscale the image.

Is there a way to prevent this without having to write an inline `style="max-width:500px"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like images with `srcset` will always upscale, even if supplied with a low-res image. It's hard to search for documentation on this because all of the examples people use assume that you already have high-res images on hand. In my case, I'm building a 'responsive image' React component that is handling images supplied by a user from a CMS. Not all of their images are high-res, though.

My solution involves a little CSS balancing of `width` and `max-width`, both on the image itself and its wrapping `<figure>` tag. (This of course could be a `div` or anything else)

**CSS:**

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

figure {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

This is generated according to how many sizes of an image are available. On the CMS side, I am creating thumbnails at 2400px, 1600px, 1200px, 800px, and 400px wide, but *only* if the source image is larger than that. The `<figure>` tag then gets all of the resized images, as well as the original one. Then, **to prevent the image from scaling up**, the `figure` tag gets a max-width of the largest image available.

So, if the source image is only 500px wide:

```
<figure class="" style="max-width: 500px;">
    <img src="http://example.com/images/img_7804a_web.jpg"
      srcset="http://example.com/images/img_7804a_web-400x600.jpg 400w,
              http://example.com/images/img_7804a_web.jpg 500w"
      sizes="100vw"
      alt="alt text">
</figure>
```

If the source image is 1125px wide, it gets a few more sources:

```
<figure class="" style="max-width: 1125px;">
    <img src="http://stephanie.standard-quality.biz/content/projects/18-2016/3-cargo-cults/cargocults_basketwoman_web.jpg"
      srcset="http://stephanie.standard-quality.biz/thumbs/projects/2016/cargo-cults/cargocults_basketwoman_web-400x533.jpg 400w,
              http://stephanie.standard-quality.biz/thumbs/projects/2016/cargo-cults/cargocults_basketwoman_web-800x1067.jpg 800w,
              http://stephanie.standard-quality.biz/content/projects/18-2016/3-cargo-cults/cargocults_basketwoman_web.jpg 1125w"
      sizes="100vw"
      alt="alt text">
</figure>
```

Here's how it ends up looking: in this instance, the third image wasn't high-res enough to span the whole column:

[image: column of images]